# Working with Pointers and Strings - how does a character turn into an integer?

Tags: c, string, pointers

I am practicing with pointers trying to familiarize myself with the ins and outs of pointers in the c-language. I have searched around the tutorials and haven't found a straight forward answer to my inquiry. Here is some code I've pieced together that demonstrates my issue. This simply sets a char pointer `*s1` to a long string and a pointer `s2` to a two letter string. The nested loop iterates through the long string looking for matches to the short string. However, I don't understand the information stored in the pointer. If I use the % Format `%d`, the pointer gives me an integer, if I use `%c` I get the letter I want. However, the line with `if (*(s1+j)!=*(s2+k))` seems to rely on the pointer being an integer and adding to it for comparison. My understanding is that the pointer just points to a memory address where this string can be found. If I add a number to the memory address, how does it move through the string? Wouldn't it point to a new memory address? Here is the code I'm working with:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

    int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

        int count, total;
        int n1,n2,i,j,k;
        char *s1 = "vrrecgcrer";
        char *s2 = "re";

        n1=strlen(s1)-1;
        n2=strlen(s2);

        printf("n1: %d, n2: %d\n",n1,n2);
        for (i = 0; i <= (n1-n2); i++){ 
            count=0;
            for(j = i,k = 0; k < n2; j++,k++){  
                printf("j is %d -- k is %d -- 1st %c -- 2nd %d\n", j, k, *(s1+j), *(s2+k));
                if (*(s1+j)!=*(s2+k)){
                    break;
                }
                else
                    count++;
                if(count==n2)
                {    
                    total++;
                }                        
            }
        }

        printf("The number of substrings is: %d\n", total);

        return 0;
    }   /* MAIN */
```

Comment: `+` is overloaded for pointers. `*(s1+j)` is the same as `s1[j]` (even if `s1` is a pointer to something larger than a `char`)

Comment: Unrelated, Fix your use of `total`, which is uninitialized at the time of your post-increment, `total++;`.  That in itself invokes *undefined behavior*.

Comment: C supports pointer arithmetic of these types: (1) adding an integer to a pointer, (2) subtracting an integer from a pointer, and (3) subtracting one pointer from another.  There are limitations.  Any C textbook worth using will cover these.  Their semantics are different, in general, from what you might expect to get by treating the pointer(s) as an integer.

Comment: A character *is* an integer. You can display it as an integer, or as the character it represents. Typically - but not necessarily - the integer is the ASCII value of the character.

Comment: So adding an integer to a pointer, in this case, moves along the string? Like `s1[j]`? Example of my output is:

      ` j is 0 -- k is 0 -- 1st v -- 2nd 114`  --- does the `114` mean anything in terms of the `r` that is stored in the first position of the second string?

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you! It didn't occur to me that it could just be the ASCII decimal code. It absolutely is that.

Comment: Moreover `printf("%zu\n", sizeof 'A');` outputs `4` on my system and not `1`!

Comment: BTW, `*(s1 + j)` is equivalent to `s1[j]`; but the addition is commutative, and so is indexing, so they're both equivalent to `*(j + s1)` and `j[s1]` - but please don't use the latter...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression in this if statement

```
if (*(s1+j)!=*(s2+k)){
```

is equivalent to

```
if ( s1[j] != s2[k] ){
```

So here there are compared two objects of the type `char` that are implicitly converted to the type `int`  due to the integer promotion rules applied to the operands when the operator `!=` is used.

From the C Standard (6.5.2.1 Array subscripting)

> 2 A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets []
>   is a subscripted designation of an element of an array object. The
>   definition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is identical to
>   (*((E1)+(E2))). Because of the conversion rules that apply to the
>   binary + operator, if E1 is an array object (equivalently, a pointer
>   to the initial element of an array object) and E2 is an integer,
>   E1[E2] designates the E2-th element of E1 (counting from zero).

In this statement

```
printf("j is %d -- k is %d -- 1st %c -- 2nd %d\n", j, k, *(s1+j), *(s2+k));
                                            ^^^
```

the expression `*(s2+k)` that has the type `char` is converted to the type `int` due to the *default argument promotions*.

From the C Standard (6.5.2.2 Function calls)

> 7 ... The ellipsis notation in a function prototype declarator causes
>   argument type conversion to stop after the last declared parameter.
>   **The default argument promotions are performed on trailing arguments**.

See the declaration of the function `printf`

```
int printf(const char * restrict format, ...);
                                         ^^^
```

As for your program in whole then it is incorrect.

For example the variable `total` was not initialized.

The condition in this for loop

```
for (i = 0; i <= (n1-n2); i++){
```

is wrong. Let's assume that the two strings have equal sizes. In this case the loop will be executed never.

Comment: Integer promotion rules are exactly what i was missing! This clears everything up for me. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Everything in C is an integer straight up. Every character is represented as an integer underneath the hood. C just knows, with the proper library, that when you use %c to show that number as a character.

Now for your issue with the following:

```
if(*(s1+j)!=*(s2+k))
```

A character is one byte. When you add a number to a pointer, such as s1+j, then you actually increment j*byteSizeofDataType. For example, to access the second r in "vrrecgcrer" you would write *(s1+2) because by default the pointer s1 points to the first character in the string. Increment by one moves the pointer one byte in memory which is where the first r is located. Increment again moves another byte which points at the second r, etc.

Strings are not a real datatype in C -- they are just arrays of characters.

Comment: *"they are just arrays of characters"* could be a bit misleading, better "*a sequence of characters terminated by a nul-byte at the end*". (It could be an array, it could just be an allocated block of memory referenced by a pointer, etc..) This is more of a nit than a ding....

Comment: That is totally fair. The null character can lead to a lot of confusion honestly so it is a good point.

Comment: Yes, and as you answer more questions here, you will find there is a great deal of confusion about what an `array` type is on the part of new C programmers. (e.g. `char *s;` does not declare an array, but it can sure point to one. `char s[] = "stuff";` or `char s[x];` does declare an `array`). So you also have to be careful with the *"they are just arrays...*" part too `:)`

Answer (score 0):

You talk of pointer arithmetic. `char *s` is NOT a pointer to string per say, it's a pointer to the 1st character of that string. Adding a number to a pointer results in pointer to ANOTHER item of that type that resides immediately after the former (and, btw, subtraction works, too).

So `s + 1` is a pointer to the 2nd character, `s + k` is a pointer to the k+1-th character. `*(s + k)` is then dereference of that pointer (i.e. the character itself).

Oh, and btw, `s[k]` is (in C) just another syntax for `*(s + k)`.

Comment: It's pretty clear he meant `Adding one to a pointer`. Be wary of being too critical before asking for clarification.